# how do I use a conditional in this one liner?

Tags: perl

I have an input file with 3 columns, and I wanted to print lines where the 3rd column hasn't been duplicated. so if my input data looks like this:

```
0,1,abc
0,2,abc
0,5,xyz
```

I would print:

```
0,1,abc
0,5,xyz
```

I initially started with the below, but it didn't produce any output. what am I doing wrong in this line?

```
perl -ne '/^[0-9]+,[0-9]+,(.+)/ && ++$a{$1} && print "$_ $a{$1}\n" if $a{$1}>0'
```

please note that I'm not looking for a solution to my problem, as I coded it in a different way. but I am interested in why the above line doesn't do what I expect, as it exposes a gap in my perl understanding.

Comment: The match never succeeds. Your pattern requires double quote characters but your data does not contain any double quote characters. DO NOT SAY "didn't work"!! Tell us what happened, no output? incorrect output? smoke came out of vents?

Comment: apologies, I've fixed the double quote problem and edited for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing, the postfix `if $a{$1} > 0` expression gets evaluated first, as if you said

```
if ($a{$1} > 0) {
    /^"[0-9]+","[0-9]+","(.+)"/ && ++$a{$1} && print "$_ $a{$1}\n"
}
```

but `$a{...}` (and `$1`) will only get updated inside the `if` block, so the `if` statement is never true.

For another thing, your regex has double quote characters but your sample input doesn't. Was that a typo?

Comment: it was a typo, I've removed the double quotes for clarity. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -ne '/^[0-9]+,[0-9]+,(.+)/ && ++$a{$1} ;print "$_" if $a{$1}==1'
```

What you posted, had also included printing the value of $a{$1}.
I assume that was for debug.

I took out the "\n"  because there is already a line feed in $1.

If you want to change that, use chomp at the beginning of the line.

Although using the && in a single line is nifty, I think it would be 
good advice to try and write the perl in a real formatted block.  This would
help you learn better, and debug easier.

Looking at your line, it is not immediately easy to see what the true intention of

```
print $_ if $a{$1}>0
```

A better approach for learning ( In my opinion ) would have been something similar 
to this:

```
perl -ne '/^[0-9]+,[0-9]+,(.+)/ and do{
   if ( ! exists $a{$1} ){
     print "$_";
   };
   $a{$1}=1;
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -ne 'print "$_ $a{$1}\n" if /^[0-9]+,[0-9]+,(.+)/ && !$a{$1}++'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -ne 'print if !$_{[m/([^,]*)$/]->[0]}++;'
```